# Unable to call the webservice by passing parameters using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I call the webservice using jquery, whenever i call, i get the error result only.
My server code:

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://xxx.xample.org")]
[WebServiceBinding( Name ="XService", Namespace="http://xxx.xample.org/XService.asmx?")]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AathiService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string IsValidUser(string UserName , string Password)
    {
       // process
       return result;

    }
}
}
```

Then i call the service using jquery like this.. .

```
 $("#okButton").click(function () {

       // CALLING WEBSERVICE

       var param = { UserName: 'xxxx', Password: 'xxxxx' };

       $.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", data: JSON.stringify(param),

           url: "http://xxx.xample.org/xService.asmx/IsValidUser", dataType: "json", async: true,

           success: function () { alert("success"); }, error: function (xhr,msg) { alert(msg + "  " + xhr.responseText); }
       });

   });
```

I am always get the error part. i doesn't know what i am done .

Comment: are you trying to do a cross domain call?

Comment: Can you get breakpoint on Function?

Answer (score 0):

in your webmethod you are expecting a "string" as return type , but you call the ajax call with datatype JSON
this should solve your problem:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public JsonResult IsValidUser(string UserName , string Password)
    {
       // process
       return Json(result);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change async: false. problem solved

Comment: 7 months later... that's some asynchronicity